# Run two jobs in parallel in one GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

Running on tensorflow, the moment that I try and run two jobs in parallel with any gpu related jobs, it flags and gives me an error regarding cuDNN module being not available. Is there any method where I can run two jobs in parallel (maybe at the cost of increased time length)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! This question is off-topic here. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details. I will migrate it to SO.

Comment: oh.. ok. Thanks for the link.